# Add links to certain columns in PHP table

Tags: php

How do I make certain columns of a php->html to be links? Currently, I am trying to fetch each header row and printing the link based on the header. Here is my code:

```
// printing table rows
$rowCtr = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($row as $cell){
        // This is the part not working.
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);

        if ($field->name == "name" || "id"){
            $link = "http://random.com?Ident={$cell}";
            echo "<td><a href='$link'>$cell</a></td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td>$cell</td>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</tr>\n';
    $rowCtr++;
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your if to this:

```
if ($field->name == "name" || $field->name == "id")
```

Comment: That's dumb! Thanks for your help.